# Get a list of questionnaires with missing answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

It's not a very good title (edits welcome) but here's a summary. The query I currently have works fine but there's probably an easier way of doing it than what I'm currently using. I have a table 'answer' with columns 'QuestionIDFK, Answer, QuestionnaireIDFK'. The data in the table is something like

```
QuestionIDFK    Answer    QuestionnaireIDFK
1               N         1
2               N         1
3               N         1
1               Y         2
2               Y         2
3               Y         2
1               N         3
3               N         3
1               Y         4
3               Y         4
```

which means the users gave an answer for question 2 for questionnaires 1 and 2 but didn't provide an answer for question 2 for questionnaires 3 and 4. What I need is a list of questionnaire IDs which don't have an answer for question 2. So the expected output is

```
QuestionnaireWithMissingAnswer2
3
4
```

I'm using this query below, which works fine but am wondering if there's an easier way:

```
SELECT distinct a.QuestionnaireIDFK AS QuestionnaireWithMissingAnswer2 
FROM Answer a
inner join (
SELECT t.QuestionnaireIDFK,
       STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + convert(nvarchar, x.QuestionIDFK)
                FROM Answer x
                WHERE x.QuestionnaireIDFK = t.QuestionnaireIDFK
                GROUP BY x.QuestionIDFK
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), ''), 1, 2, '') 
                AS QuesList
     FROM Answer t
     GROUP BY t.QuestionnaireIDFK) z 
ON z.QuestionnaireIDFK = a.QuestionnaireIDFK AND z.QuesList NOT LIKE '%2%'
```

Comment: you have not provided complete info .Like there must be another table for Questionnaire along with QuestionID list.
Then why not select * from QuestionnaireTable where not exists(select * from Answer ).Something like this .

Comment: @KumarHarsh There's a table 'Question' with question IDs but different questionnaires have different questions. One questionnaire will have 10 questions, another questionnaire will have 25 questions, your suggestion makes sense but all I can work with is questionnaires and the answers provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just use `not exists` or `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
select QuestionnaireIDFK
from answer
group by QuestionnaireIDFK
having sum(case when QuestionIDFK = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This gets all questionnaires that do not have question #2 (at least all questionnaires that have some answer).

You can also do this with `not exists` (or a `left outer join`):

```
select distinct QuestionnaireIDFK
from answer
where not exists (select 1
                  from answer a2
                  where a.QuestionnaireIDFK = a2.QuestionnaireIDFK and
                        a2.QuestionIDFK = 2
                 );
```

However, because of the `distinct`, this is unlikely to have better performance than the first method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a left outer join, joining on both the key and the answer id, then filter out successful joins using the where clause:

```
select q.*
from Questionnaire q
left join Answer a on a.QuestionnaireIDFK = q.id
    and a.QuestionIDFK = 2
where a.QuestionnaireIDFK is null
```

It makes quite a neat and efficient query and works because the where clause, which is applied after the join is made, can only be true if the join is missed. The "trick" is putting the condition on question into the join condition, which is evaluated during the join (putting the condition on question in the where clause would effectively make it an inner join).

Also note you don't ever get duplicates, because there's only ever one row returned from the main table when the join us missed.

Also note that a questionnaire doesn't need to have any answers at all for this to work.